# Odd Illegal Variable Name error in csh script

Tags: scripts, tcsh, csh

I have a peculiar problem with a csh script which occurs only in my Lenovo Z500 laptop. I have run the script in 3 other computers with analogous operating systems (Kubuntu 14.04 x64) and the only system that faced this error was mine. The script has been written to automate a download process. I'm badly stuck. PLEASE HELP!

the command that I use to run the script: `xargs -I ds ./exportfile.csh ds afo_rk@yahoo.com <pt`

csh script :

```
#! /bin/csh -f
#
# Updated 27 July 2015 to deal with changes for more compact json output format.
#         also added tests for wget failures
# updated 20 March 2015 to deal with new need to not urlescape to words on left of '='
#
# Simple script to fetch a JSOC recordset using calls to wget
#
# call with a two arguments containing a recordset query and your registered email address
# resulting data files are placed into the current directory
#
# see http://jsoc.stanford.edu/jsocwiki/AjaxConnect for further information
#
# e.g.
#   exportfile.csh 'hmi.M_45s[$]' XXX@YYY.ZZZ
# will get you the most recent SDO/HMI line-of-sight magnetogram if you replace the XXX@YYY.ZZZ with your
# registered email address (see below)

set noglob

if ($#argv != 2) then
  Two args required, recset and notify
  call=$argv
  exit
endif

# get desired recordset and encode for transmitting
# you can get the following url_escape script at http://jsoc.stanford.edu/ajax/

set ds=`./url_escape.pl "$1"`

# You MUST now include a valid registered email address.  You can use a prior exportdata "notify" email address
# or just make one via http://jsoc2.stanford.edu/ajax/register_email.html
# Change the '$2' in the line below to your notify address if you want the script to not need a second argument.

set notify = `./url_escape.pl "$2"`

# for FITS without full headers use fastest method use the next 2 lines:

# set method=url_quick
# set protocol=as-is

# if, as is most common, you want full FITS headers or
# if you want to specify the filename format for the returned data or if you expect multiple
# files you should use the next two lines.

set method=url
set protocol="FITS"

# to specify filename formats add the "filenamefmt" command to the cmd line below.
# you will need to url_escape the filenamefmt. 

set ffmt = `./url_escape.pl 'hmi.sharp_cea_720s.{HARPNUM}.{T_REC:A}.{segment}'`

set op=exp_request

set cmd = "op=$op&ds=$ds&process=n=0|no_op&method=$method&format=txt&protocol=$protocol&filenamefmt=$ffmt&notify=$notify&requestor=none&sizeratio=1"

set JSOC="http://jsoc.stanford.edu"
set FETCH="$JSOC/cgi-bin/ajax/jsoc_fetch"

# Make a place to put the handshake information
set RESP = /tmp/jsoc_export.$$

wget -S -nv -O $RESP  $FETCH?"$cmd"
if ($?) then
  wget failed, response was: $RESP
  exit
endif

if ($method == "url") then
  set Status = "`grep status $RESP | sed -e 's/[{}]//g' -e 's/: / = /' -e 's/"status"/Status/' -e 's/,.*//'`"
  set $Status
  if ($Status == 4) then
    echo "Export request failed, status=" $Status
    cat $RESP
    echo "Command was " $cmd
    exit
  else if ($Status == 6) then
    echo "Problem with finding registered email address."
    cat $RESP
    exit
  endif

  set requestid = `grep requestid $RESP`
  if ($#requestid == 0) then
    echo no requestid found
    exit
  endif
  set $requestid

  # wait for processing to complete, do status query with sleeps and initial sleep
  set qry = "op=exp_status&requestid=$requestid&format=txt"
  while (1)
    sleep 3
    wget  -S -O $RESP $FETCH?"$qry"
    if ($?) then
      wget failed, response was: $RESP
      exit
    endif
    set Status = "`grep status $RESP | sed -e 's/[{}]//g' -e 's/: / = /' -e 's/"status"/Status/' -e 's/,.*//'`"
    set $Status
    if ($Status == 0) break
    if ($Status == 6) then
        continue
    else if ($Status > 2) then
        echo Error in processing export request
        echo possibly bad recordset format or no data in SUMS
        cat $RESP
        exit
    endif
  end

else if ($method == "url_quick") then
  set Status = "`grep status $RESP | sed -e 's/[{}]//g' -e 's/: / = /' -e 's/"status"/Status/' -e 's/,.*//'`"
  set $Status
  if ($Status == 4) then
    echo "Export request failed, status=" $Status
    cat $RESP
    echo "Command was " $cmd
    exit
  else if ($Status == 6) then
    echo "Problem with finding registered email address."
    cat $RESP
    exit
  endif
endif

set dir = `grep dir $RESP`
set $dir
set count = `grep count $RESP`
set $count

# Now $RESP contains headers used above and table of count files.
# loop through files and fetch them.

while ($count > 0)
  set REC = `tail --lines=$count $RESP | head -1`
  set QUERY = $REC[1]
  set FILE = $REC[2]
  set URL = $JSOC$dir/$FILE
  echo Fetching $QUERY as `basename $FILE`
  wget -S -nv $URL
  if ($?) then
    wget failed, response was: $RESP
    exit
  endif
  @ count = $count - 1
  end

# remove working file.  Parhaps useful to save with the data.
# rm $RESP
mv $RESP ./


# The cgi-bin programs that you can use with wget or curl or such programs include
#   jsoc_fetch
#   jsoc_info
#   show_series
#   show_info
#
#   If you need to pass flags (e.g. -X) to these programs, use 'X=1' on the urlencoded command line.
#   To see the full set of options see the man pages in doxygen from the jsoc2 home page.
#
# If you want to run exportfile.csh to fetch a group of recordsets you can place them
# into a file, one line per recordset, with surrounding single quotes, and no internal spaces.
# then use xargs to bring the set of recordsets, one at a time.
```

url_scape.pl :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI; print CGI::escape($ARGV[0]); print "\n";
```

pt.txt :

```
'hmi.sharp_cea_720s[][2010.02.05_18:47_TAI-2010.02.05_18:59_TAI][? NOAA_ARS ~ "11045" ?]{Bp,Br,Bt}'
'hmi.sharp_cea_720s[][2010.02.06_02:20_TAI-2010.02.06_02:32_TAI][? NOAA_ARS ~ "11045" ?]{Bp,Br,Bt}'
'hmi.sharp_cea_720s[][2010.02.07_21:01_TAI-2010.02.07_21:13_TAI][? NOAA_ARS ~ "11045" ?]{Bp,Br,Bt}'
'hmi.sharp_cea_720s[][2010.02.11_11:19_TAI-2010.02.11_11:31_TAI][? NOAA_ARS ~ "11046" ?]{Bp,Br,Bt}'
```

Konsole Output :

```
afshinrk-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/export> xargs -I DS ./exportfile.csh DS afo_rk@yahoo.com < pt
xargs -I DS ./exportfile.csh DS afo_rk@yahoo.com
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:50:09 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
  Connection: close
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/plain
2016-02-09 17:20:10 URL:http://jsoc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/ajax/jsoc_fetch?op=exp_request&ds=hmi.sharp_cea_720s%5B%5D%5B2012.07.05_10%3A24_TAI-2012.07.05_10%3A36_TAI%5D%5B%3F%20NOAA_ARS%20~%20%2211515%22%20%3F%5D%7BBp%2CBr%2CBt%7D&process=n=0%7Cno_op&method=url&format=txt&protocol=FITS&filenamefmt=hmi.sharp_cea_720s.%7BHARPNUM%7D.%7BT_REC%3AA%7D.%7Bsegment%7D&notify=afo_rk%40yahoo.com&requestor=none&sizeratio=1 [127] -> "/tmp/jsoc_export.2786" [1]
Illegal variable name.
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:50:12 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
  Connection: close
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/plain
2016-02-09 17:20:12 URL:http://jsoc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/ajax/jsoc_fetch?op=exp_request&ds=hmi.sharp_cea_720s%5B%5D%5B2012.07.05_13%3A26_TAI-2012.07.05_13%3A38_TAI%5D%5B%3F%20NOAA_ARS%20~%20%2211513%22%20%3F%5D%7BBp%2CBr%2CBt%7D&process=n=0%7Cno_op&method=url&format=txt&protocol=FITS&filenamefmt=hmi.sharp_cea_720s.%7BHARPNUM%7D.%7BT_REC%3AA%7D.%7Bsegment%7D&notify=afo_rk%40yahoo.com&requestor=none&sizeratio=1 [127] -> "/tmp/jsoc_export.2791" [1]
Illegal variable name.
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:50:14 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
  Connection: close
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/plain
2016-02-09 17:20:16 URL:http://jsoc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/ajax/jsoc_fetch?op=exp_request&ds=hmi.sharp_cea_720s%5B%5D%5B2012.07.05_18%3A48_TAI-2012.07.05_19%3A00_TAI%5D%5B%3F%20NOAA_ARS%20~%20%2211515%22%20%3F%5D%7BBp%2CBr%2CBt%7D&process=n=0%7Cno_op&method=url&format=txt&protocol=FITS&filenamefmt=hmi.sharp_cea_720s.%7BHARPNUM%7D.%7BT_REC%3AA%7D.%7Bsegment%7D&notify=afo_rk%40yahoo.com&requestor=none&sizeratio=1 [127] -> "/tmp/jsoc_export.2796" [1]
Illegal variable name.
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:50:18 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
  Connection: close
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/plain
2016-02-09 17:20:19 URL:http://jsoc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/ajax/jsoc_fetch?op=exp_request&ds=hmi.sharp_cea_720s%5B%5D%5B2012.07.06_03%3A10_TAI-2012.07.06_03%3A22_TAI%5D%5B%3F%20NOAA_ARS%20~%20%2211515%22%20%3F%5D%7BBp%2CBr%2CBt%7D&process=n=0%7Cno_op&method=url&format=txt&protocol=FITS&filenamefmt=hmi.sharp_cea_720s.%7BHARPNUM%7D.%7BT_REC%3AA%7D.%7Bsegment%7D&notify=afo_rk%40yahoo.com&requestor=none&sizeratio=1 [127] -> "/tmp/jsoc_export.2801" [1]
Illegal variable name.
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:50:20 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
  Connection: close
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/plain
2016-02-09 17:20:21 URL:http://jsoc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/ajax/jsoc_fetch?op=exp_request&ds=hmi.sharp_cea_720s%5B%5D%5B2012.07.06_10%3A57_TAI-2012.07.06_11%3A09_TAI%5D%5B%3F%20NOAA_ARS%20~%20%2211515%22%20%3F%5D%7BBp%2CBr%2CBt%7D&process=n=0%7Cno_op&method=url&format=txt&protocol=FITS&filenamefmt=hmi.sharp_cea_720s.%7BHARPNUM%7D.%7BT_REC%3AA%7D.%7Bsegment%7D&notify=afo_rk%40yahoo.com&requestor=none&sizeratio=1 [127] -> "/tmp/jsoc_export.2806" [1]
Illegal variable name.
```

Comment: Don't link to files. Paste the relevant code here and format it as code by pressing `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: `Two args required, recset and notify` looks like an error (i.e. missing `#` mark), as does the next line (`call=$argv`). At any rate, the fact that tcsh  **can't even tell you which line the error occurred** is the sort of reason why scripting in `csh` is *strongly* discouraged. Try running it with `tcsh -x` to see what is going on. Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand why it works just fine in other systems other than mine. If the code had some snags, it would give out the same error in every one of them as well.

Comment: I ran the code with `-v` and it turned out that the problem was the variable `$?` .

Answer (score 0):

I ran the script with `-v` and it turned out that the problem was the variable `$?`.